# how to use global variables in php class in a MVC project

Tags: php, model-view-controller, session, model, global-variables

I want to `$st_id` in a function in my model class in a mvc project, as you see below, but it get me an error that `$st_id` is not defined. what I can do for resolve this problem ?

```
<?php

@session_start();
$st_id=$_SESSION['username'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))
{
header('Location: signin.php');
}
//////////////////////    
class model
{
    private $result;
    public $rp_result;
    //////////
    public function exe_query()
    {
        $mysqldb = new MySQLDatabase();
        $result=$mysqldb->query('CALL view_report('.$this->st_id.');');
        $this->rp_result=$mysqldb->fetch_all($result);
    }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare it within the class if you're using it with `$this`

```
class model {
    public $st_id;

    public function __construct() {
        @session_start();
        $this->st_id = $_SESSION['username'];
    }

    public function exe_query()
    {
        $mysqldb = new MySQLDatabase();
        $result=$mysqldb->query('CALL view_report('.$this->st_id.');');
        $this->rp_result=$mysqldb->fetch_all($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How do you call your model ?

I suggest you:

```
class model
{
    private $result;
    public $rp_result, $st_id;

    public function __construct($st_id)
    {
        $this->st_id = $st_id;
    }

    public function exe_query()
    {
        $mysqldb = new MySQLDatabase();
        $result=$mysqldb->query('CALL view_report('.$this->st_id.');');
        $this->rp_result=$mysqldb->fetch_all($result);
    }
}
```

And now, you can use:

```
@session_start();
$st_id=$_SESSION['username'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']))
{
    header('Location: signin.php');
}

$model = new model($st_id);
$model->exe_query();
```

Comment: you say I use sessions in my controller class ? What is your opinion about MR Matt above your answer ?

Comment: I'm asking you about how do you use your `model` class. The Matt answer is ok every time your `$st_id` is the same as `$_SESSION['username']`. If for one reason or another, you need `$st_id` to be something else, it won't work.

Comment: Ok,Thanks.I want to call it from a function in controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call it directly as `$_SESSION['username']`? It's already global...

Comment: How ? please clarify your idea.

Comment: @JavadYousefi $_SESSION is always available as long as `session_start()` has been invoked. Setting a variable to its value is unnecessary. I think that's what Truth was trying to say.